# Dummy Operator fails with state: upstream_failed

Tags: airflow

I have a dag which creates the EMR cluster as below:

```
STEP_CONFIG = dict(
    CLASS="fooA",
    JAR=DEFAULT_JAR,
    PROPERTIES="fooA.properties",
    ACTION_ON_FAILURE="CONTINUE"
)


DEFAULT_ARGS['start_date'] = dt.datetime(2019, 12, 18)

with DAG(
        DAG_NAME,
        default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
        dagrun_timeout=dt.timedelta(hours=2),
        schedule_interval='@daily',
        catchup=False
) as dag:
    compose_dag_for_ltc(LONG_TERM_CLUSTER_NAME, JOB_NAME, STEP_CONFIG)

add_step >> step_added >> watch_step >> all_steps_finished
```

The dag successfuly creates the EMR cluster and add all the steps but some times it happens that all_steps_finished task fails with state: upstream_failed. The failure is not on the EMR side but rather on the airflow side. It also does not produce any logs which makes it harder to diagnose. Any ideas what might be happening here ?

Comment: What is all_steps_finished ?

Comment: @Elad its a Dummy Operator.  DummyOperator(task_id='all_steps_finished')

Comment: Are you running Airflow 1.10 or 2?

Comment: its version: 1.10.4

Comment: So I would say - there is no good explanation. In Airflow 2 DummyOperators with all_success trigger rule are automatically set to Success they don't run on worker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are running on old Airflow version this is probably a bug which was fixed later. There is no good reason to explain what you are experiencing.

In Airflow 2 `DummyOperator` and any operator that inherits from it will not be considered by the scheduler for execution (if it has no actual work to be done) see the [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/e6c56c4ae475605636f4a1b5ab3884383884a8cf/airflow/models/dagrun.py#L808-L816) in that case the task will simply be marked Success. So what I can say is that when you upgrade to Airflow 2 the problem will most likely be solved.